# Passing a function to odeint that should decrease according to each time step in the solution of odeint

Tags: python, physics, odeint

I want one of the parameters i pass to odeint to be a function.

In my case, this is the Hubble constant H which should decrease with H ~ 1/t.

This time "t" is exactly the same time that my odeint uses for solving coupled ODEs.
(I want to solve equations of motion in an expanding universe and want H to be determined outside of odeint so to speak)

How do i tell odeint that i want H to be decreasing with each time step that odeint is calculating?

The relevant lines from my code are (Here, H is a constant (H=1) but i want it to be H=1/t):

```py
def func(X, t, parameters):
    theta, alpha, phi, beta = X      # unpack current values of X
    Lambda, fa, H = parameters  # unpack parameters
    derivs = [alpha, -2*beta/phi*alpha - 3*H*alpha , beta, -3*H*beta + alpha**2 *phi -Lambda**2 *phi**3 + fa**2 * phi] # list of derivatives
    return derivs
 
# Set initial (angle, angularvelo, radius, radialvelo) & bundle them to pass to odeint
theta0, alpha0, phi0, beta0 = np.pi, 30, 4, 100
X0 = [theta0, alpha0, phi0, beta0]
 
# Set time & stepsize. T should be time for 1 Period in the future.  
T = 5 tmax, dt = 1*T, T/10000
t = np.arange(0, tmax, dt)
# Set Parameters & bundle them to pass to odeint  
H = 1 
Lambda = 30
fa=1.5
parameters = [Lambda, fa, H]
# Call the ODE solver
(solution, restoffulloutput) = odeint(func, X0, t, args=(parameters,), full_output=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works just fine.

It's as simple as just defining the function inside your odeint function since it is "t" that odeint is iterating over.

```
def func(X, t, parameters):
    theta, alpha, phi, beta = X      # unpack current values of X
    Lambda, fa, H = parameters  # unpack parameters
    H = 1/t # this line is doing the job
    derivs = [alpha, -2*beta/phi*alpha - 3*H*alpha , beta, -3*H*beta + alpha**2 *phi -Lambda**2 *phi**3 + fa**2 * phi] # list of derivatives
    return derivs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest approach would be to make a class for the value that is decreasing with each time step.

```
class MagicValue:
    def __init__(self, initial_value):
        self._value = initial_value

    @property
    def next_value(self):
        # modify self._value here
        return self._value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

Now modify your function to take in a MagicValue and use the properties as required.

Comment: It may make more sense to add a method that causes the change.  `magic_value.do_time_step()` and then refer to `magic_value.value` as required.  (NOTE: If you don't use the value of `magic_value.next_value` you essentially have this method already.